# Le mot « rourage »

Tags: vocabulaire, france

Que signifie le mot « rourage » ? On le trouve dans *La Petite Fadette* de George Sand.

> Le père Barbeau était un homme de bon rourage, pas méchant et très porté pour sa famille, sans être injuste à ses voisins et paroissiens.

La définition n'est pas au TLFi et le Web ne fournit pas d'indications.

C'est un mot qui est aussi inconnu du [Littré](https://www.littre.org/recherche?mot=rourage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nous ne devons pas chercher loin. George Sand a écrit « courage », et non pas « rourage » (mot qui sans doute n'existe pas), voir par example [l'édition de 1852](https://fr.m.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Sand_-_%C5%92uvres_illustr%C3%A9es_de_George_Sand,_vol_1,_1852.djvu/104) :

[image]

Comment: Très évidemment c'est une erreur dans mon édition papier.